# Youtube API - Channel Comments Moderation

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

is there any way how to get all video comments for given channel through Youtube API v3? I need it to manage classic comment moderation.

Many thanks for all ideas and tips!

Best,

Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for video comments in v3 of the API. You can still do this in v2 however but it is now deprecated.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments

Comment: Any idea how long v2 could works? Is there any chance that Google add such method also in v3?

Comment: It seems Google plan to support this API method also in V3, but until it will be ready, they recommend us to use V2. See what Goodle says:

While the new comments aren’t currently supported in the YouTube Data API v3, you can continue to use the older version of the API (v2) with a few caveats outlined below (and the benefits covered above).

Comment: From what I can tell they completely cut it off after a year. You'd be better off asking on the Google forums as their staff actually read the posts.